# Stochastic differential - notation

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

Assume we have processes $A,B,C$ s.t. $A=\int_0^tB_udC_u$ where $C$ is of bounded variation. Now, there is a notation to write this equation as $dA_t=B_tdC_t$. I saw somewhere that one can now go on to define B as $B_t=\frac{dA_t}{dB_t}$. How is this justified and what does $\frac{dA_t}{dC_t}$ mean?

Comment: I suppose you mean $B_t = \frac{dA_t}{dC_t}$...?

Comment: @saz Yes. Thanks.

Comment: Well, if you divide $$dA_t = B_t \, dC_t$$ (formally) by $dC_t$ you get $$B_t = \frac{dA_t}{dC_t}.$$ It means exactly what is written in the first line of your question: $$B_t = \frac{dA_t}{dC_t}$$ iff $$A_t-A_0 = \int_0^t B_u \, dC_u.$$

Comment: @saz What i get is that $dC_t(\omega)$ can be identified with a signed measure and i learned that $dA_t=B_tdC_t$ is just a notation for the integral of B w.r.t C. So how is it justified to simply divide here?

Comment: If a measure $\nu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to a measure $\mu$, then $\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}$ is a standard notation for the density of $\nu$ with respect to $\mu$ (which exists by Radon-Nikodym). For this reason it is kind of natural to write $B_t = \frac{dC_t}{dA_t}$ because it is the analogon for signed measures. (And obviously you can't divide by differentials; it's just a formal thing which gives you some intuition why this notion is used.)